# Rails Filterrific - live update not working

Tags: filterrific

It says [here](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/action_view_api.html), in the *view* API, that if I put `class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed'`, then whatever search string I put, it updates *live* (without the need of pressing enter).

However, in my code, it does not live update; rather, I have to press *enter* to trigger a search (which works, but would be very nice with live updates).

Here is my code!

```
 #index.html.erb

<%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific, :html => { class: 'ui form' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :search_query, class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed', placeholder: 'search by name, merc or map' %>
    <%= link_to 'Reset filters', reset_filterrific_url, class: 'ui inverted basic button', id: 'reset-filters' %>
    <!--<%= link_to 'cancel', '#', :class => 'ui inverted basic button', id: 'cancel-button-search', remote: true %>-->
<% end %>
```

I searched a lot regarding this issue, but I didn't find anything specific to *filterrific*. Did I miss an important step?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to add the following line to 'app/assets/javascripts/application.js':

```
//= require filterrific/filterrific-jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to put `<div id="filterrific_results">` in your partial, like so:

```
<%# app/views/YOUR_MODEL/_YOUR_PARTIAL.html.erb %>
<div id="filterrific_results">
  #your partial here
</div>
```